# Azure DevOps Collection Settings

Tags: azure, azure-devops, storyboard, agile

For those who have setup Azure DevOps with a Collection (Not an Organization), is it possible to do the following:

1. Add custom "Process" fields into the like say "States" on the agile process? For some reason this button is disabled on the "Collections" options
2. Is it possible to add a more columns to our sprint board? It seems like we can add things to our "board" but the sprint board we are not able to add any new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add custom "Process" fields into the like say "States" on the agile process? For some reason this button is disabled on the "Collections" options

It seems that you are using `Inheritance` process. If you want to edit the process(e.g. add new state to work item), you need to create an inherited process.

[image: Inheritanced]

This option is in `Collection Settings -> Process`. Then you could custom the process in the inherited process.

[image: inherited Process]

> Is it possible to add a more columns to our sprint board?

Since you are using the Inheritance Process and Collection, it seems that there is **no** option to add the column in the `Sprint -> taskboard`.

By the way, this feature supports in the **Organizaiton**.

Here is the doc about the [taskboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/customize-taskboard?view=azure-devops-2019), you could refer to it.

**Updates:**

Since you are using the hosted Process, you could try the following steps to add the new state and column.

Here are the steps:

1. Export Process through WitAdmin command or `Export` option.
2. Navigate to `WorkItem Tracking -> Process ->ProcessConfiguration.xml`.
3. Add state item in TaskBacklog => States section (Add Column). If you want to add state to other work items, you could add to state to other Backlog category.

For example:

```
<States>
  <State type="Proposed" value="To Do" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="Review" />
  <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
</States>
```

4. Import modified work item file and process file to the team project
5. Check the result in web access.

For more details how to use WitAdmin command to export and import process configure file. Please refer our official tutorial here--[Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&redirectedfrom=MSDN) .

Comment: The problem is we can "create inherited process" we can only upload a template. Which appears to be because we are on premise server.

Comment: Hi @SetupG. From you reply, it seems that you are using the hosted xml process. If yes, you could add column in Taskboard and state to work item. Please check the update.

Comment: Awesome! I saw this, my only question is that wont break anything by just adding that will it? Lets say it does is it easy to revert?

Then also one last thing, to add a column to the sprint board would be a matter of searching for it in the files that get exported?

Comment: Yes. It will not break existing settings. It will only change the settings you modified. And it is indeed easy to revert. For the last thing, you could get the configuration file in the exported files. Then you could modify it.